# How to know if a specific app comes to foreground?

Tags: java, android

Check if an app, for example, Instagram is started by user.

Note: My app is targeting lollipop and above versions in android

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the only way you can do it is through the Accessibility Service.  Look at this page to understand how to create it.  https://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html  They will also need to enable the service via the services -> accessibility screen.

AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED  you can probably interrogate the package in front to figure out if Instigram is on top.

You definitely don't want to use getRunningTasks since the function was modified in Android 5.0+

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I can do this by using usage access feature.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public static String getForegroundProcess(Context context) {
    String topPackageName = null;
    UsageStatsManager usage = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<UsageStats> stats = usage.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000*1000, time);
    if (stats != null) {
        SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> runningTask = new TreeMap<Long,UsageStats>();
        for (UsageStats usageStats : stats) {
            runningTask.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
        }
        if (runningTask.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        topPackageName =  runningTask.get(runningTask.lastKey()).getPackageName();
    }
    if(topPackageName==null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    return topPackageName;
}
```

Now continuously check if the desired app is in the foreground.

```
String fg=getForegroundProcess(getApplicationContext());
    if(fg != null && fg.contains("com.instagram.android")){
       //Instagram is in foreground
    }else {

    }
```

I continuously run the above code with a job service.Which is available for 
lollipop and above.